# Always rewrite a baseurl to /my-page

Tags: .htaccess

For many reasons, I need to rewrite my Base URL to a page, which is a hub.

i.e. http://data.mydomain.com always directs the user to http://data.mydomain.com/my-page

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-page/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try anything?
/?$ /my-page

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you htaccess :

```
RewriteEngin on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^data.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /my-page [L,R=301]
```